# If $(X,Y)$ is a Gaussian random vector, is also $(X,Y,1)$ a Gaussian random vector?

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

if $(X,Y)$ is a Gaussian random vector, can we say that $(X,Y,1)$ is also a Gaussian random vector?

I know that in order to prove this I need to find:

$ \begin{pmatrix}X\\ Y \\ 1  \end{pmatrix} = 
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12} \\ a_{21}&a_{22} \\ a_{31}&a_{33}  \end{pmatrix} }_{A}
 \begin{pmatrix}X\\ Y \\  \end{pmatrix} $

but the $A$ that I found includes: $\frac{1}{2}  X^{-1}$, $\frac{1}{2}Y^{-1}$ in its arguments, and thats not a deterministic matrix.

what I'm missing here?

Comment: If (X,Y) has p.d.f. $p(x,y)=f(x,y)$ than (X,Y,Z=1) has p.d.f. $p(x,y,z)=f(x,y)*\delta(z-1)$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function. Do not know if this helps ?

Comment: It will be a degenerate normal distribution, so won't have a density wrt Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Yes, the transformation is
$$\begin {pmatrix} X \\ Y \\ 1 \end {pmatrix} =
\begin {pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end {pmatrix}
\begin {pmatrix} X \\ Y \end {pmatrix} +
\begin {pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end {pmatrix},$$
so if $(X, Y)$ is a normal random vector, $(X, Y, 1)$ is also a normal random vector. If $\boldsymbol X \sim \mathcal N(\boldsymbol \mu, \Sigma)$, then $A \boldsymbol X + \boldsymbol a \sim \mathcal N(A \boldsymbol \mu + \boldsymbol a, A \Sigma A^t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider **any real number as a Gaussian random variable with mean equal to itself and variance equal to $0$**, then yes.

Comment: Okay, sounds logical. but in this case we can't find a matrix $A$ as I described above ?

Comment: No, because no linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ can have zero variance, or if it does, the coefficients $a_{31}$ and $a_{32}$ must be zero which leads to impossible $1=0$.

Comment: Thanks! that really helped!

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck!